# Windows 8 : AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603

Tags: windows-8, appfabric

While installing AppFabric 1.1 on windows 8, I'm getting this error.

**AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603**

Can someone let me know solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205927/appfabric-installation-failed-because-installer-msi-returned-with-error-code-1)

Comment: but i am not able to resolve this issue from there. Is it resolved for windows 8