# How to change environment variable with powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

When Installing AppFabric in windows 2012 R2 I found this problem:
[AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205927/appfabric-installation-failed-because-installer-msi-returned-with-error-code-1)

I am trying to make an automated script for my Sharepoint 2013 Installation with powershell

Is it possible to change this with powershell? and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the variable temporarily with:

```
$env:PSModulePath = "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\"
```

Or you can change it permanently with:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\", "Machine")
```

Be aware that if you try to change it permanently at the "Machine" level, anything that has already loaded the Environment with NOT pick up the changes until the Environment is reloaded, i.e. anything already running will need to restart.

You can also just do both so that the first one changes the Process variable for anything run after that then the second one changes the Machine variable and then do a restart soon after so everything picks up the new Environment.