# Installing AppFabric 1.1 with PowerShell DSC results in modal dialog error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, appfabric, dsc

I'm trying to automate the installation of AppFabric 1.1 on a Windows 2012 R2 server using PowerShell DSC.  This is actually part of me trying to automate the SharePoint Foundation install and configuration, but AppFabric 1.1 is a pre-requisite.  Below is a snippit from my DSC config script:

```
Script InstallSharePointPreRequisites
    {
        GetScript = { Return "InstallSharePointPreRequisites" }
        TestScript = {$false}
        SetScript = { 
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi' -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait | Write-verbose 
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\setup_msipc_x64.msi' -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait | Write-verbose
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\sqlncli.msi' -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait | Write-verbose
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\Synchronization.msi' -ArgumentList '/qn' -Wait | Write-verbose
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\WcfDataServices.exe' -ArgumentList '/quiet' -Wait | Write-verbose
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\appfabric\setup.exe' -ArgumentList '/i cacheclient","cachingService","CacheAdmin /gac /l c:\temp\appfabric.log' -Wait | Write-verbose
            Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\SharePoint\pre\AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe' -ArgumentList '/quiet' -Wait | Write-verbose
        }
        DependsOn = "[File]GetSharePointFiles"
    }
```

I know....the "TestScript = $false" is bad form, but I'm just trying to get the install to run at this point. :)

Anyway, when the DSC run get to the appfabric\setup.exe it's throwing the following exception:

"{"Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application."}"

When I run the Start-Process line from a normal PS prompt it installs fine and doesn't show a visible modal dialog box.  I've also tried using the AppFabric setup EXE with similar switches with the same result.  I'm sort of at a loss here.  Has anyone else been able to install AppFabric 1.1 using PowerShell DSC?  Or SharePoint Foundation 2013 for that matter?  If so, how?  I haven't been able to find good documentation on this scenario yet.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.  First, there was a typo in my script.  The app fabric setup line had `CachAdmin` rather than `CacheAdmin` (was missing the 'e' in cach**e**).  It took me some time and writing it a few more times to figure that out.  After setting that, it is installing fine.  Darn, old eyes and fat fingers...  Thanks for looking. :)

A