# Error Installing AppFabric in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, appfabric

I have tried installing AppFabric multiple times on Windows 10 Pro as an administrator. I have read many posts related to it. Somewhere it is mentioned to delete `AS_OBSERVER` or delete `PSModulePath`. I have tried both but still I couldn't able to install.

The error log is as follows:

```
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2015-11-12 10:26:44-08:00 =====
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  File:             c:\4edb67880c60dcfa5814780a9bd89e\setup.exe
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows 10 Pro
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                Professional
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            en-US
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2015-11-12 10:26:44, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2015-11-12 10:26:54, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2015-11-12 10:26:54, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2015-11-12 10:26:54, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2015-11-12 10:26:54, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2015-11-12 10:26:54, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\4edb67880c60dcfa5814780a9bd89e\Microsoft CCR and DSS Runtime 2008 R3.msi" /l*vx "C:\Users\MAshhad\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2015-11-12 10-26-54).log"
2015-11-12 10:26:55, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000000
2015-11-12 10:26:55, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2015-11-12 10:26:55, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\4edb67880c60dcfa5814780a9bd89e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheService,CacheClient,CacheAdmin,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\MAshhad\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2015-11-12 10-26-55).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\MAshhad\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2015-11-12 10-26-55).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2015-11-12 10:27:18, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000643
2015-11-12 10:27:18, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2015-11-12 10:27:18, Error                 Setup  
2015-11-12 10:27:18, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2015-11-12 10:27:18, Error                 Setup  
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Required Windows components   :  Completed Successfully
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console            :  Completed Successfully
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft CCR and DSS Runtime 2008 R3         :  Completed Successfully
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  :  Failed
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Hosting Services          :  Failed
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Caching Services          :  Failed
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Cache Client          :  Failed
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration            :  Failed
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Cache Administration          :  Failed
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update  :      Skipped
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update          :  Skipped
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  
2015-11-12 10:27:19, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped:  2015-11-12 10:27:19-08:00 =====
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205927/appfabric-installation-failed-because-installer-msi-returned-with-error-code-1)

Comment: This question was asked for Windows 10. The duplicate you commented is not for Windows 10.

Comment: It's the exact same error, what makes you think Windows 10 is special?

Comment: I have tried everything that is mentioned on stackoverflow for Windows 10, but nothing worked.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14282121/68432

Comment: I got similar problems when I have GitHub for Windows on same machine just remove temporarily the ~/.ssh folder and it is installing OK.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Installation

- 1. Make sure you have both "remote registry" and "windows update service" installed.
- 2. If you have previously attempted an install, you may have a couple of groups marked as AS_ in your user manager, make sure you delete these "AS_XXXX" -- delete these.  I found that I would still get a 1603 after attempting again.
- 3. Run your installation and you should get success.